# Convert firebase json to typescript array

Tags: arrays, json, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework

I can easily get the data working in my HTML, but when I have to convert it for visualization purposes it is a struggle.

I get the data as a FirebaseListObservable. In my case there's 3 value-types in each List, but it is only one of them there has to be part of the array. How do I convert a FirebaseListObservable to an array in typescript?

The reason of converting is to use graphs in my app.

Typescript getting the data:

```
this.measure= this.db.list('/Users/'+this.username+'/Measure');
enter code here
```

Typescript for chartjs

```
this.data = [12, 24, 91, 23]
```

The data has to be the data from the firebase

Comment: posting with some code will increase the chance of getting answered.

Comment: @Hareesh -I have updated it. Thanks for mentioning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare a empty array `data=[];`

then get the data with `.subscribe()`

```
this.db.list('/Users/'+this.username+'/Measure').subscribe(measures => {
    measures.forEach(measure => {
      this.data.push(measure.number);//.number should be your field in firebase
    })
  })
```

this will fetch all list and search through all items and push your desired values to the array.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

`FirebaseListObservable` is an observable. That means you will get the list itself (=the array you want) when you **subscribe** to it.

```
this.measure: FirebaseListObservable<Measure[]> = this.db.list('/Users/'+this.username+'/Measure');
this.measure
    .map(measurement => measurement.numbers) // this extracts only numbers field so we have basically array of arrays
    .map(numbersArrays => numbersArrays.reduce((curr, prev) => curr.concat(prev))) // so lets concat all those arrays into a single one
    .subscribe(numbersArray: number[] => {
        console.log(numbersArray);
    });

interface Measure {
    data: Date;
    geolocation: string;
    numbers: number[];
}
```

Comment: I will try that, thanks. Measure holds both the numbers, date and geolocation.

Comment: I've added interface for `Measure`

Comment: Okay so I got this now:
   
    this.db.list('/Users/'+this.username+'/Measure').subscribe(items => {
    console.log(items);
    });

I can see the data in my console. How do I save the numbers in an array?

Comment: So what do you want to do with those measurements now? There are numbers on each item of that list. Do you want to just join them together?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want. Like this [30,40,20,10,30]

Comment: @JacobKurtsen updated the answer. You should subscribe to that observable in your component to retain the observable clear.